# Passing arguments to mpmath quad integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpmath

I'm integrating some pretty nasty functions, and scipy.integrate.quad is not handling the situation very well. I was planning to use mpmath.quad with tanh-sinh method, but I need to pass some arguments to the function that is being calculated, like this:

```
mpmath.quad(f,[0,mpmath.pi],method='tanh-sinh',args=(arg_1, arg_2))
```

as f is defined as

```
f(x,arg_1, arg_2)
```

Didn't find anything like that on the doc. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lambda:

```
import mpmath
arg_1 = 1
arg_2 = 9

print mpmath.quad(lambda x: f(x, arg_1, arg_2), ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint that tanh-sinh quadrature is also available without mpmath, via [tanh_sinh](https://github.com/nschloe/tanh_sinh) (one of my packages). If your function has extra parameters, you can always just wrap the function, like so:

```py
import tanh_sinh
import numpy


def fun(x, a):
    return a * numpy.exp(x) * numpy.cos(x)


val, error_estimate = tanh_sinh.integrate(
    lambda x: fun(x, 1),
    0,
    numpy.pi / 2,
    1.0e-14,
    # Optional: Specify first and second derivative for better error estimation
    # f_derivatives={
    #     1: lambda x: numpy.exp(x) * (numpy.cos(x) - numpy.sin(x)),
    #     2: lambda x: -2 * numpy.exp(x) * numpy.sin(x),
    # },
)

print(val, error_estimate)
```

I like this approach better than passing the args because it's more explicit.